# Hit Enter Key in a Sub Form Can Force Me Back to Main Form

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, enter

Before I describe the problem, let me explain what the program is like:

I have a program that I am using one window to be the host to show all the sub-forms. This one window (main-panel-form) has a Panel control. I attach a sub-form into the panel control to show the sub-form, and then detach it and attach another sub-form to it. By doing this way, the user only sees one window from my application instead of seeing multiple windows from my app. The main-panel-form has a mechanism to manage the attaching/detaching of sub-forms and the communication between sub-forms.

When the program starts, main-panel-form attaches the main-menu sub-form into its Panel control.  When the user chooses a menu option from the main-menu sub-form, the main-menu sub-form tells the main-panel-form the option that the user has selected via a call-back-function.  At that point, the main-panel-form will detach the main-menu sub-form from Panel control (hide it, not destroy it), and then attach the sub-form corresponding to the user's selected option to the Panel control.

Everything works fine other than the fact that the attach/detach mechanism is quite complicated. The complicity is not the problem. The problem is that when the user hits Enter key in the sub-form, the program will kick the user back to the main-panel-form instead of letting the sub-form to deal with the Enter key. This problem only happens when the user has opened the sub-form once before. Remember above that after I have detached the sub-form, I keep the sub-form hidden, I don't destroy it. Somehow this triggers the error.

I can get around this problem by destroying the sub-form whenever it is detached from the Panel control (and then re-create it when it is needed). But my application requires that the info in the sub-form should remain in place when the user returns back to the sub-form. The easiest way to accomplish this is to hide the sub-form and then unhide it when I need to show it again.

I am currently working around this problem by trapping and discarding the  key in ProcessCmdKey() event handler. But this seems like a hack and doesn't really fix the source of the problem. Moreover, if the sub-form needs to do something about the Enter key (such as trying to convert Enter key into a Tab key), I will need to tell ProcessCmdKey() not to do this for that sub-form. Strangely, in that case, I need to ask ProcessCmdKey() in main-panel-form not to do this for the sub-form (instead of asking ProcessCmdKey() in the sub-form not to do this) -- that's why I say this is a hack.

The following is the simplified version of the main-panel-form where I believe the source of the problem is likely to be:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;           // For using Debug.Assert().
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestEnterKeyProblem
   {
   // Constants related to calling back functions
   // -------------------------------------------

   public enum MainMenu_SelOpt : int
      {
      DlgBoxNormal        = 1,
      DlgBoxChgEnterToTab = 2
      }

   // Delegates for call-backs from this sub-form
   // -------------------------------------------

   // Call back function to communicate from the
   // main-menu to this main panel.
   public delegate void CallBackFuncFromMainMenu
      (
      MainMenu_SelOpt fMenuOptSelected
      );

   // Call back function to communicate from the
   // dialog-box-normal to this main panel.
   public delegate void CallBackFuncFromDlgBoxNormal();

   // Call back function to communicate from the
   // dialog-box-change-enter-to-tab to this main panel.
   public delegate void CallBackFuncFromDlgBoxChgEnterToTab();

   // Definition of frmMainPanel
   // --------------------------

   public partial class frmMainPanel : Form
      {
      // These flags tell us which sub-form is the active form
      public enum ActiveFrm : int
         {
         Is_MainMenu            = 31,
         Is_DlgBoxNormal        = 32,
         Is_DlgBoxChgEnterToTab = 33
         }

      // Data members

      //....This flag indicate which window in this application
      //....has the input focus.
      private ActiveFrm activeFrm = ActiveFrm.Is_MainMenu;

      //....The following are the sub-forms that can be attached
      //....to the main panel control of this object.
      private frmMainMenu            subfrmMainMenu            = new frmMainMenu();
      private frmDlgBoxNormal        subfrmDlgBoxNormal        = new frmDlgBoxNormal();
      private frmDlgBoxChgEnterToTab subfrmDlgBoxChgEnterToTab = new frmDlgBoxChgEnterToTab();

      // Class constructor

      public frmMainPanel()
         {
         InitializeComponent();

         this.activeFrm = ActiveFrm.Is_MainMenu;
         }

      // Event handlers

      private void frmMainPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
         // Attach the main-menu sub-form to the panel-control.
         this.AttachMainMenuSubFormToPanelCtrl();
         }

      // Attach various sub-forms to the panel control in this form.

      private void AttachMainMenuSubFormToPanelCtrl()
         // Attach the main-menu sub-form to the panel control.
         // Note: We don't detach the main menu sub-form. This means we only
         //       need to use this routine to attach the main menu sub-form
         //       only once. We detach all other sub-forms.
         {
         // Attach the main-menu sub-form to the panel.
         this.subfrmMainMenu.TopLevel = false;
            // Set it to false because we cannot add a top-control
            // into another control (the main panel).
         this.panelMain.Controls.Add( this.subfrmMainMenu );

         // Tell the main menu sub-form which function to call back.
         CallBackFuncFromMainMenu funcCallBackFromMainMenu =
            new CallBackFuncFromMainMenu( this.OnCallBackFromMainMenu );
         this.subfrmMainMenu.SetCallBackFunc( funcCallBackFromMainMenu );

         // Now, we can activate the main menu.
         this.subfrmMainMenu.Visible = true;
         this.activeFrm = ActiveFrm.Is_MainMenu;
         }

      private void AttachDlgBoxNormalSubFrmToPanelCtrl()
         // Attach the dialog-box-normal sub-form to the panel-control.
         {
         // Attach the dialog-box-normal sub-form to the panel.
         this.subfrmDlgBoxNormal.TopLevel = false;
            // Set it to false because we cannot add a top-control
            // into another control (the main panel).
         this.panelMain.Controls.Add( this.subfrmDlgBoxNormal );

         // Tell the dialog-box-normal sub-form which function to call back.
         CallBackFuncFromDlgBoxNormal funcCallBackFromDlgBoxNormal =
            new CallBackFuncFromDlgBoxNormal( this.OnCallBackFromDlgBoxNormal );
         this.subfrmDlgBoxNormal.SetCallBackFunc( funcCallBackFromDlgBoxNormal );

         // Now, we can hide the main menu and show the
         // dialog-box-normal sub-form.
         this.subfrmMainMenu.Visible = false;
         this.subfrmDlgBoxNormal.Visible = true;
         this.activeFrm = ActiveFrm.Is_DlgBoxNormal;
         }

      private void AttachDlgBoxChgEnterToTabSubFrmToPanelCtrl()
         // Attach the dialog-box-change-enter-to-tab sub-form to the
         // panel-control.
         {
         // Attach the dialog-box-change-enter-to-tab sub-form to the panel.
         this.subfrmDlgBoxChgEnterToTab.TopLevel = false;
            // Set it to false because we cannot add a top-control
            // into another control (the main panel).
         this.panelMain.Controls.Add( this.subfrmDlgBoxChgEnterToTab );

         // Tell the dialog-box-change-enter-to-tab sub-form which
         // function to call back.
         CallBackFuncFromDlgBoxChgEnterToTab funcCallBackFromDlgBoxChkEnterToTab =
            new CallBackFuncFromDlgBoxChgEnterToTab( this.OnCallBackFromDlgBoxChgEnterToTab );
         this.subfrmDlgBoxChgEnterToTab.SetCallBackFunc( funcCallBackFromDlgBoxChkEnterToTab );

         // Now, we can hide the main menu and show the
         // dialog-box-change-enter-to-tab sub-form.
         this.subfrmMainMenu.Visible = false;
         this.subfrmDlgBoxChgEnterToTab.Visible = true;
         this.activeFrm = ActiveFrm.Is_DlgBoxChgEnterToTab;
         }

      // Call-back function

      public void OnCallBackFromMainMenu
         (
         MainMenu_SelOpt fMenuOptSelected
         )
         // The main menu sub-form tells the main panel which
         // menu option that the user has selected.
         {
         ////////////////////////////////////////
         if ( this.activeFrm != ActiveFrm.Is_MainMenu )
            {
            String sCurActiveForm = "N/A";
            if      ( this.activeFrm == ActiveFrm.Is_DlgBoxNormal        ) sCurActiveForm = "Is_DlgBoxNormal";
            else if ( this.activeFrm == ActiveFrm.Is_DlgBoxChgEnterToTab ) sCurActiveForm = "Is_DlgBoxChgEnterToTab";

            String sCurMenuOptSelected = "N/A";
            if      ( fMenuOptSelected == MainMenu_SelOpt.DlgBoxNormal        ) sCurMenuOptSelected = "DlgBoxNormal";
            else if ( fMenuOptSelected == MainMenu_SelOpt.DlgBoxChgEnterToTab ) sCurMenuOptSelected = "DlgBoxChgEnterToTab";

            String sDebugMsg =
               String.Concat( "frmMainPanel.cs - OnCallBackFromMainMenu() : ",
                              "Active form is supposed to be 'Is_MainMenu'; but it is '", sCurActiveForm, "'. ",
                              "Please note that menu-option-selected is '", sCurMenuOptSelected, "'. ",
                              "This is an error." );
            MessageBox.Show( sDebugMsg, "Assertion Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error );
            }
         ////////////////////////////////////////
         Debug.Assert( fMenuOptSelected == MainMenu_SelOpt.DlgBoxNormal        ||
                       fMenuOptSelected == MainMenu_SelOpt.DlgBoxChgEnterToTab );

         if      ( fMenuOptSelected == MainMenu_SelOpt.DlgBoxNormal        ) this.AttachDlgBoxNormalSubFrmToPanelCtrl();
         else if ( fMenuOptSelected == MainMenu_SelOpt.DlgBoxChgEnterToTab ) this.AttachDlgBoxChgEnterToTabSubFrmToPanelCtrl();

         // Note: We don't detach the main menu sub-form from the
         //       main panel control.
         }

      public void OnCallBackFromDlgBoxNormal()
         // The dialog-box-normal sub-form tells the main panel
         // that the user is done.
         {
         Debug.Assert( this.activeFrm == ActiveFrm.Is_DlgBoxNormal );

         // Detach the dialog-box-normal sub-form from the main panel
         // control. We don't delete it. We keep it hidden.
         this.subfrmDlgBoxNormal.Visible = false;
         this.panelMain.Controls.Remove( this.subfrmDlgBoxNormal );

         // Go back to the main menu.
         this.subfrmMainMenu.Visible = true;
         this.activeFrm = ActiveFrm.Is_MainMenu;
         }

      public void OnCallBackFromDlgBoxChgEnterToTab()
         // The dialog-box-change-enter-to-tab sub-form tells the
         // main panel that the user is done.
         {
         Debug.Assert( this.activeFrm == ActiveFrm.Is_DlgBoxChgEnterToTab );

         // Detach the dialog-box-change-enter-to-tab sub-form from the
         // main panel control. We don't delete it. We keep it hidden.
         this.subfrmDlgBoxChgEnterToTab.Visible = false;
         this.panelMain.Controls.Remove( this.subfrmDlgBoxChgEnterToTab );

         // Go back to the main menu.
         this.subfrmMainMenu.Visible = true;
         this.activeFrm = ActiveFrm.Is_MainMenu;
         }

      }
   }
```

When the user hits Enter key in the sub-form (after the sub-form has been opened once before), the program somehow will go to OnCallBackFromMainMenu() in the main-panel-form shown above (instead of allowing the sub-form to handle the Enter key, or going back to the call-back function for the sub-form).

I tried to attach a working version of the sample program. But I don't see how to do this in this forum. If you want to try the sample program, please let me know, and I will upload it to a public FTP site.

I cannot figure out this. Would you please help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Jay Chan

Answer (score 0):

A guess... since I don't see the relevant code of the form:

The enter key is trigger a `Button` Click event on the form.  The button has its `DialogResult` property set to something other than `None`.

Comment: Thanks.  But.  No, the AcceptButton of all the forms are (none).  And the DialogResult of all the buttons in the program is left at None.

Comment: To see how the problem is, please download the ZIP file of the source code of the working version of the program from this [link](https://www.mediafire.com/?m1qzo96i6i4ybjs).  It is a simplified program just to show the problem.  Compile and build it, run it to see the main menu.  From the main menu, choose any one of the link to see a sub-form, close the sub-form, back to the main menu, and choose the same link one more time, see the same sub-form, and then hit Enter key and see the error message.

Comment: @JayChan Unable to use this zip file, missing all required files from subdirectories (AssemblyInfo, Resources.resx, etc)

Comment: Sorry for the fact that the last ZIP file was missing the "Properties" sub-folder.  I have uploaded a new ZIP file that includes the missing "Properties" sub-folder and all the other files.  You can download from this [link](https://www.mediafire.com/?f79d94f82r34j9d).  And thanks for trying to help me.